# Commenting a default constructor when writing a class

Tags: java, constructor, documentation, comments, default-constructor

In my Java basic class my teacher told me to comment any arbitrary choice that I make when I write a default constructor for a class. (She told us that we must create a default constructor for every class that we design) So for example, I'm writing a class named RoomDimension, and I created a default constructor as follows:

```
public class RoomDimension {

    //Fields
    private double length;          //Length of a carpet
    private double width;           //Width of a carpet

/**
*
*/
public RoomDimension(){ 
        length = 0.0; 
        width = 0.0;
    }
```

I'm using here 0.0 as my flag to indicate the user has entered nothing or an invalid input. Should I then comment the fact that 0.0 is used as an indication of an invalid input in the documentation comment(/**/)? I know that if I were to use -1 as my flag (or an initialization of a field in default constructor), I would definitely comment that -1 indicates an invalid input because I made that decision arbitrarily. I'm asking whether 0 has to be commented or not because I don't know if 0 is an arbitrary choice or not. Would you, as a programmer, bother to indicate that? Or, is it okay if I just assume that the user knows it without telling them?

Comment: _"She told us that we must create a default constructor for every class that we design"_ I can't believe that! You teacher should know, that a default constructor is created  by the compiler for classes where no constructor is explicitly written. Also your example itself shows why a default constructor for _just to have one_ is evil: you never know if the values in the properties are valid. At least you have to check each time you access them.

Answer (score 0):

As to whether zero should be commented, I think it would be best to indicate it is a flag in order to remind yourself in the future, or any other programmer that looks at your code.

As for using zero as a flag, I think it would be better practice to throw an exception when length and height are less than or equal to zero. It would be easier to read in the future, and more efficient to handle when a user does enter a non-positive number.

Answer (score 0):

> She told us that we must create a default constructor for every class
>   that we design

And I told for my teacher: Who don't know is teaching, who know is doing!

If you don't create a default constructor, the compiler will do it, did you know? - how about your teacher?

Many tools, which generates, transform data will cry, nags, crash if they don't find a COMPILED "default constructor". But they will completely ignore the comments.

So back to your class:

```
public class RoomDimension {

 static {
  System.out.println("I an a static initializer, If the classloader will touch your class, I will be called first! ex. RoomDimension.anyStaticmethod() or before new RoomDimension()");
 }

 {
  System.out.println("I am instance initializer. whenever you call any constructor, I will run before the constructor body, try me with: new RoomDimension()");
 }

 //Fields
 private double length; //Length of a carpet
 private double width; //Width of a carpet

 public RoomDimension() {
  length = 0.0;
  width = 0.0;
 }
}
```

By the way in your code:

```
public RoomDimension() {
  length = 0.0;
   width = 0.0;
 }
```

it is completely useless, because before constructor, it will be an initialisation and that will do exactly the same, because you have declared as properties and they will be initialize, before constructor:

```
 private double length; //Length of a carpet
 private double width; //Width of a carpet
```

If you want to know it is initialized or not, use `Double` instead of `double` and check for `null` value.

Ex:

```
private Double length; //Length of a carpet
private Double width; //Width of a carpet
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked her if it is okay to leave out a default constructor because my textbook pointed out that java compiler would provide one for me if I don't have one, and she said that the compiler would do it for me only when there is no other constructor in my class. Is it true? Should I then create one just for a habit?

Answer (score -2):

I would set the values of those to be nullable.

```
    public class RoomDimension 
{
private double? length;
private double? width;

}

    public RoomDimension()
{  

}
```

What this does for you is allow the values of length and width to take the value of null. So when you call the default constructor, they are automatically set to null.

This will help you start thinking in terms of objects, because when you have objects that contain other objects you cant set all the contained objects to 0.0, you just create a null object. Also when you perform actions on that object you just check if its null beforehand this helps to avoid null reference exceptions.

Comment: It is not `C#` question.

Comment: Sorry change double? to Double and you are in java